# How to move deleted data to another table in Yii 2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have two tables such as `Employee` and `DeletedEmployee`.

What I need is while am deleting data in `employee` table, that specific data must be move to `deletedemployee` table.

**DeletedEmployee** table's structure is as below :

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
emp_name varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
emp_age varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
emp_address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
emp_phone varchar(45) NOT NULL,
emp_designation varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

**Employee**

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
age varchar(45) NOT NULL,
address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
phone varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
designation varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: do you want the SQL query?

Comment: i need to solve this, so what ever it is. how to do this using coding

Comment: Please provide with the database structure so that I can write proper query for you

Comment: You can use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) . This will move records to your other table everytime you delete some thing from Employee tabel

Comment: **deletedemployee**
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_age` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_phone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_designation` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
**employees**
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `age` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Comment: that is what i dont know how to do that trigger..pls help me

Comment: @KalaiS Please update your initial question instead of posting it as comment. And also learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on SO.

Comment: @KalaiS : please see the answer posted and ask if you have any doubts

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ActiveRecord::afterDelete()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave()-detail). Since the current object has not yet been destroyed you can get the required fields. Assuming you have a model `DeletedEmployee` you can do the following in your `Employee` model:

```
public function afterDelete() {
    $deletedEmployee = new DeletedEmployee;
    $deletedEmployee->id = $this->id.
    //assign other attributes
    $deletedEmployee->save();
    parent::afterDelete();
}
```

Comment: @KalaiS, this seems to be working, maybe you have some errors?

Comment: i have paste this code in employeecontroller , and generated model for deletedemployee, then finally i deleted a data in employeetable, but doesnt get a deleted employee data in deletedemployee table

Comment: This goes in the `Employee` model. Not the controller.

Comment: if i paste that code in model, where i can call that function

Comment: You do not need to call it anywhere as long as you are deleting the employee via `$model->delete()`. Follow the link in the answer for more information.

Comment: this is the controller code to delete  public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } how i can use here

Comment: @KalaiS did you found out a way ?

Answer (score 1):

The trigger , as the name suggests can be used to initiate some action when some event occurs like for eg : Insert,Update,Delete,etc.

The query could be as follows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trgAfterDelete
AFTER DELETE ON Employee
AS
    insert into DeletedEmployee values(val1,val2,val3,....)

    PRINT 'AFTER DELETE TRIGGER fired.'
GO
```

You can learn to enable the trigger from this [link.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182706.aspx)

Comment: i cant understand how to use this and where to use this in yii2

Comment: I am not aware about this framework .. But that is a different problem I guess. You should google it to see how to use it . My answer is solution to your question!